# Laravel обработка всех запроса без указания пути

Tags: php, laravel, requests, controller, route

Собственно хочется обрабатывать все входящие запросы и вывести их на экран.
Проблема в том, что в route-ах нужно указать конкретный путь например

```
Route::get('/user', function(Request $request){
     dd($request)
}
```

или

```
Route::get('/', function(Request $request){
     dd($request)
}
```

Но в этом случае обрабатываются только маршруты, которые указаны, а не все.

Т.е. что-то типа

```
Route::get('all_request', function(Request $request){
         dd($request)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы ищите [резервный маршрут](https://laravel.com/docs/routing#fallback-routes):

```php
Route::fallback(function () {
    //
});
```

> Резервный маршрут всегда должен быть последним маршрутом,
> зарегистрированным вашим приложением